# Get a list of API products via Azure RM powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-api-management, azure-rm

Is there a way to get list of API products via Azure RM powershell module?

In Az powershell module it can be done with command Get-AzApiManagementProduct by pasing -ApiId to it.

Comment: Use [Get-AzureRmApiManagementProduct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.apimanagement/get-azurermapimanagementproduct?view=azurermps-6.13.0) to get list of api product.

Comment: Any update now? If it helps you, please accept it as answer.(click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Get-AzureRmApiManagementProduct` with `New-AzureRmApiManagementContext` to get the list of api product.

```
$ApiMgmtContext = New-AzureRmApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "yourresourcegroup" -ServiceName "yourapimname"
Get-AzureRmApiManagementProduct -Context $ApiMgmtContext -ApiId $apiname
```

[image]

Comment: But it will return all Products, when I need to get a list of only those Products specific API was added to.
There is a way to do it with Az module (Get-AzApiManagementProduct has ApiId param where I can specify necessary API), but is there a way to get this info with a help of Azure RM module.

Comment: Yes, you could use `Get-AzureRmApiManagementProduct -Context $apimContext -ApiId $apiname` to achieve it.

Comment: I have update my reply, if it helps you, please accept it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: When I try to run this command with -ApiId, such error is returned:
"Get-AzureRmApiManagementProduct : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ApiId'."

Code looks like:
`code`
$apimContext = New-AzureRmApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName $rgName -ServiceName $apimName
Get-AzureRmApiManagementProduct -Context $apimContext -ApiId $apiId
`code`
---
AzureRM version = 6.13.1
AzureRM.ApiManagement version = 6.1.7

Are there some reasons why this ApiId parameter is not available in some cases (like for me)?

Comment: Actually, the AzureRm module will be deprecated and it will never update. The reason why I success is I use [Try it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.apimanagement/new-azurermapimanagementcontext) in this link. That will auto [Enable-AzureRmAlias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/enable-azurermalias?view=azps-2.8.0) to enables AzureRm prefix aliases for Az modules.

Comment: So, I still suggest you to use az module with Get-AzApiManagementProduct .

Comment: Thanks much for your help.
Yes, I'm going to use Az module, just was wondering whether there is such possibility with Azure RM or I'm just doing something wrong and thus it is not available.